# wp_maintenance_mode - Boolean True/False not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a define where I am able to enable and disable the WP maintenance mode with true or false. Logged in users and people who can edit the theme are able to visit the site.

But for some reason.. the function will always return "false". even with true and false set.

Am I missing something out?

Code:

```
<?php

// Enable maintenance mode
define('NM_ENABLE_MAINTENANCE_MODE', false);

if(NM_ENABLE_MAINTENANCE_MODE && !current_user_can('edit_themes') || !is_user_logged_in()) {
    function wp_maintenance_mode() {
        wp_die('<h1>' . NM_MAINTENANCE_TITLE . '</h1>' . '<p>' . NM_MAINTENANCE_MESSAGE) . '</p>';
    }
}


add_action('get_header', 'wp_maintenance_mode');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I look at this as a truth table. You have three variables A,B,C and the current statement says `(A ∧ B ∨ C)` which isn't what you want. Instead the truth table for `(A ∧ (B ∨ C))` is what you want. That would say IF `NM_ENABLE_MAINTENANCE_MODE` is `true` AND user cannot edit themes OR user is not logged in SHOW the page. So they could be logged in but NOT be allowed to edit themes then they should see the page.

`A` = Constant for `NM_ENABLE_MAINTENANCE_MODE`

`B` = INVERSE of `current_user_can('edit_themes')` (so cannot edit themes)

`C` = INVERSE of `is_user_logged_in()` (so not logged in)

```
A   B   C   SHOW PAGE
T   T   T   T
T   T   F   T
T   F   T   T
T   F   F   F
F   T   T   F
F   T   F   F
F   F   T   F
F   F   F   F
```

I believe the code you are looking for is (function only if IF is true):

```
<?php

// Enable maintenance mode
define('NM_ENABLE_MAINTENANCE_MODE', false);

if(NM_ENABLE_MAINTENANCE_MODE && (!current_user_can('edit_themes') || !is_user_logged_in())) {
    function wp_maintenance_mode() {
        wp_die('<h1>' . NM_MAINTENANCE_TITLE . '</h1>' . '<p>' . NM_MAINTENANCE_MESSAGE) . '</p>';
    }
    add_action('get_header', 'wp_maintenance_mode');
}
```

Code if you want the function to always be available:

```
<?php

// Enable maintenance mode
define('NM_ENABLE_MAINTENANCE_MODE', false);

function wp_maintenance_mode() {
   if(NM_ENABLE_MAINTENANCE_MODE && (!current_user_can('edit_themes') || !is_user_logged_in())) {
        wp_die('<h1>' . NM_MAINTENANCE_TITLE . '</h1>' . '<p>' . NM_MAINTENANCE_MESSAGE) . '</p>';
    }
}
add_action('get_header', 'wp_maintenance_mode');
```

EDIT: Moved the add_action inside of the IF statement so you don't get the undefined function error.

Comment: This works almost but get the following - The only thing i get now is: [11-Mar-2021 14:06:36 UTC] PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wp_maintenance_mode' not found or invalid function

Comment: Edited the above, sorry about that. I forgot to move the adding of the action inside of the IF statement. Otherwise you would need to have the `function wp_maintenance_mode()` be on the outside of the IF. You could also bring the IF inside fo the function. Really either way is up to you.